# Exclude double characters in a string

Tags: regex

It's actually simple to do, but I'm stucked in this solution.

---

I have a list of random characters with a *length of 20* contains only capital **characters** and **numbers**. As example.

```
NC6DGL2L41ADTXEP20UP
F3KB7UXUBD5089BKANOY
A5P3UI57KW18UNF89AKL
6O36RJHDLNXW8Y1O1GBC
6CVAT6LTAHEKDRCB9KNH
K20L4MQRA5C677P2NNV8
726WYBOO0X7UTFMSN6VT
AYBECMW9AVJX9AX5F1ZZ
HWKWU0BEIWLHZZJYKDC1
TXLF9FYNIVZ7SHR92ZIH
```

My goal is to choose only these who doesn't contain a double character in an order like this.

```
F3KB7UXUBD5089BKANOY
```

I don't want strings like this, because there is a **N** character in an order.

```
NC6NNNN41ADTXEP20UP
```

Comment: I got a regex which does the exact opposite, dont know if it can help you :  `(.).*\1`

Comment: What is your language / environment?

Comment: @revo I don't use any language. I'm just learning using an online tool.

Comment: Double characters include double numbers? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @revo Yes. It cannot contain double characters include numbers.

Comment: Do the two characters have to be folowed or not ? If they have to be followed then it would be `(.)\1`

Comment: I don't want to be followed.

Comment: Check this https://regex101.com/r/P5N60L/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?!^.*([A-Z0-9])\1.*$)^[A-Z0-9]+$
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tTZM7z/2)

Negative Lookahead to make sure that 2 of the same characters do not sit together

(Edited to increase performance, see the other version through the demo link, v1 of the regex).

**Breakdown of the regex:**

- `(?!` - start of the negative lookahead
- `^` - from the start of the string
- `.*` - any character, any amount of times
- `([A-Z0-9])` - capture a character in the ranges given
- `\1` - the same characters as the first capture group
- `.*$` any character, any amount of times until the end of the string
- `)` close negative lookahead

This section therefore means, outside of this, do not match anything that from start to finish contains 2 of the same character (in the ranges `A-Z` and `0-9`) sitting together.

- `^` - from the start of the string
- `[A-Z0-9]+` - a character in the ranges given, one or more times
- `$` - until the end